# CFBundleURLTypes doesn't change

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, url, plist

I'm currently trying to change the value of CFBundleURLTypes in the .plist file to a new value but it seems that nothing has an effect and the old value is still present if I call

```
NSLog(@"%@", [[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"CFBundleURLTypes"]);
```

I searched the whole project for the old value but the old value is nowhere present. I cleaned the project twice but it doesn't have an effect. Does the suppurted URL Schemes get cached somewhere? 
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

It's not cached; the main bundle is read-only on iOS, because changing it would invalidate the signature. Possibly barring jailbreaking, I don't think there's a way to alter the Info plist after deployment.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. Problem was that I added an extra target to the app and the extra .plist for the target was not included in the project, so changes doesn't had an effect.